# multiple runtimes in a single bluemix app?

Tags: python, node.js, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to run a hobby project on bluemix that is a combination of nodejs and python, that expects the runtimes to be collocated.

At first, I didn't even know there was a python dependency.  So I deployed based on the node SDK starter app.

There is a "requirements.txt" for python dependencies, but I can see it's not really being used. Is there something I can do to get deployment to recognize that the app is a hybrid like this, IOW to process the requirements.txt so when python is invoked my deps are there?

Comment: Full disclosure: I really have no clue about python, node.js, or bluemix so I may have already mislead above.

This is someone elses hobby project I'd like to run on bluemix to feed a slack integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would recommend splitting the application up so they do not have this dependency. But if you can't, I can think of two options:

1. Use [multi-buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi). Create the `.buildpacks` file in the application root directory and push your application with `-b https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git` option. During staging, the buildpacks specified in that file will be called on your application.
2. Write your own [custom buildpack](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/custom.html). It's not that difficult and you can only do the minimum your application needs.

Comment: Tentatively, multi-buildpack might be doing the trick. It looks like my python deps are now there.

Comment: This worked with a weird false start where the python side broke due to using heroku buildpacks directly.  $ cat .buildpacks 
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack.git